# Empirical characteristic function

Tags: probability-theory, characteristic-functions

The ecf is $\phi_n(\omega) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^ne^{iX_j\omega}$. I'm stuck on trying to see why the following is true $$|\phi_n(\omega)|^2 = \phi_n(\omega)\phi_n(-\omega)$$ Wouldn't this imply that $\phi_n(\omega)=\phi_n(-\omega)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true because $\phi_n(-\omega)=\overline{\phi_n(\omega)}$ (as long as $\omega$ is real not complex). Thus, you get
$$
|\phi_n(\omega)|^2
=\phi_n(\omega)\overline{\phi_n(\omega)}
=\phi_n(\omega)\phi_n(-\omega).
$$